# How to define a npm module requirea babel transplie

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I have created a npm module and it uses babel to translate `es6`/`es7`. And I have defined the `prepublish` as below:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "babel -d dist/ src/",
    "prepublish": "yarn run build",
  },
"main": "dist/index.js",
```

when I run `npm publish` I can see that it runs `prepublish` to compile the code to `dist` directory. So I defined the `main` entry point to `dist/index.js`.

But in other project which has a dependency on this module, I defined the dependency as below:

```
"devDependencies": {
    ...
    "mongo-shell-translator": "0.0.1-alpha.6",
    ...
}
```

when I run `yarn install` I can see that this dependency has been downloaded under `node_modules` but the `dist` directory is not generated. So my project reports an error saying that `Error: Can't resolve 'mongo-shell-translator'`. 
How to let the other projects run `babel` during `yarn install`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do that, just transpile the source into dist and add this field to package.json:

```
"files": [
    "dist"
 ]
```

That will include the folder into the npm repository and since your main is pointing to it you are already pointing to the transpiled version.